# running blazor from visual studio code

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

i have created a blazor app via command line, now I am trying to run this app from visual studio code, when i start running VSC ask me to chose an environment . which environment should I use to run the application ?

Comment: When you run the app from VS Code what do you mean? Are you running it from the terminal in VSC or using a plugin?

Comment: i am not running it from terminal, but from VSC by pressing F5, i have already installed C# extension but it shows me this : cannot create .NET debug configurations. The OmniSharp server is still initializing or has exited unexpectedly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So right now running Blazor apps using F5 in VS Code is not supported. There's currently an issue tracking this https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/3024.

For now you can run Blazor applications using the terminal and the following dotnet CLI command in the same directory as the csproj file.

```
dotnet run
```

Comment: If you're happy this answers your question could you please mark it as the accepted answer so others can benefit. Thanks.

Comment: i have tryed to do it but i am not allowed because i am a new student

Comment: Anyone who asks a question has the rights to mark the answer. There should be a tick to the left of my answer you can click. Once it goes green its done.